# There are $n$ points in a plane, no three of which collinear. Find Number of diagonals in a polygon of $n$ sides.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Q-There are $n$ points in a plane, no three of which collinear. Find the number of diagonals in a polygon of $n$ sides.

Note I found error was with formula used to find number of triangles.

My attempt

In $n$ points there are ${n}\choose{3}$ triangles. 
So, a polygon formed by ${n}\choose{3}$ triangles will have ${{n}\choose{3}} + 2$ sides (I got this result by noticing series like square have 2 triangles, pentagon have 3 triangles,.....)

And a polygon of $n$ sides have $\frac{n(n-3)}{2}$ diagonals . 
Hence ${{n}\choose{3}} + 2$ sides will have $\frac{1}{2} \Big[\big( {{n}\choose{3}}\big[{{n}\choose{3}} + 2\big] + 2\big) -3\Big]$ diagonals .

But in textbook it's answer is ${{n}\choose{2}}-n$

What mistake I had done. Please help me to find out error

Please note that I am a highschool student seeking help from teachers, so please don't close my question.

Thanks everyone for paying attention to my question!!!!!

Comment: You construct diagonals with $2$ points... So,  $\binom{n}{2}$ . Again , the sides of polygon aren't diagonals... So,  $\binom{n}{2}-n$ .

Comment: @Entrepreneur  Thanks sir,  I got it .But i want to know why answer is not coming by this method

Comment: How many triangles does a hexagon have? You must go through your first argument.

Comment: @Entrepreneur Hexagon = 4 triangles  it goes perfect with my pattern of n-2

Comment: No.  It has $6$ of 'em

Comment: @Entrepreneur what is wrong with hexagon

Comment: I'm just trying to say that you're first argument doesn't satisfy the higher polygons...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81901/discussion-between-rafael-nadal-and-entrepreneur).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist to make a conclusion starting from the number of triangles...

Say that you have $n$ points: $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n$.

These points define $\binom n3$ triangles. The total number of edges in all these triangles is: $3\times\binom n3$. However each edge is counted several times. For example, edge $A_1A_2$ appears in triangles $A_1A_2A_3$, $A_1A_2A_4$, ..., $A_1A_2A_n$ which means that each edge appears exactly $n-2$ times in all possible triangles.

So the total number of lines is actually:

$$\frac{3\times \binom n3}{n-2}$$

Not all lines are diagonals. You get the number of diagonas by subtracting the number of polygon sides $n$ from the total count of lines:

$$\frac{3\times \binom n3}{n-2}-n=\frac{3\times\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3\times2\times1}}{n-2}-n=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-n=\binom n2-n$$

The most complicated way to count the number of diagonals, but you asked for it :)

Comment: There is a quicker way of getting to ${n \choose 2}$ as the number of lines joining two of the $n$ points

Comment: @Henry please read my introduction... and conclusion. Submitter asked for a triangle-based proof, not the easiest one. Each vertex of the polygon participates in exactly $n-3$ diagonals with each diagonal counted twice. So the total number of diagonals is $\frac{n(n-3)}2$